# Is a valid approach to state Active Record Associations in mixin modules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mixins

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 and I would like to know if it is a *valid* approach to state a [Active Record Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in a mixin module. *Why?*

More:

1. what are advantages and disadvantages of this approach?
2. is there something to which I should pay attention to?
3. is there some prescription to make that?

---

*Note*: I would like to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) my code since statements related to my Active Record Associations are the same for multiple models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and do it! Regarding your questions:

- Regarding 1: The biggest advantage is that you have a clean code base with no duplicated code; the biggest disadvantage I can think of is that it might not be instantly obvious to someone looking through your code.
- Regarding 3: You have to define the associations either in the `included` callback or using the new `ActiveSupport::Concern` extensions for it.

Example:

```
# using the standard include callback
module LocationAwareness

  def self.included(base)
    base.has_one :location
  end
end
```

or

```
# using ActiveSupport::Concern
module LocationAwareness
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    base.has_one :location
  end
end
```

then you can use it in your models like that:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  include LocationAwareness
end

class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base
  include LocationAwareness
end

#...
```

This approach of course starts to make even more sense if you have more shared behaviour than "just" the association...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but you must take care of doing it in an `included do...end` block.

In my opinion, even if it is not for DRY and just to encapsulate behavior, it's very worth do separate a model's code into independent modules.